# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection Evaluation of Tree

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is there an easy way to evaluate that the dependencies are available within the DI container for either a given service or all services? (Specifically at build time)

I have a couple of Azure Functions running that I manually build the DI container for to keep the content to a minimum and when the dependency tree changes I have to remember to add the new dependency to the function. If I don't I get an error when the function executes the first time not when I build it to republish.

Is there a best practice to follow with this? Can it be achieved with some sort of unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to validate this at build time, but as you suggest, you could verify this with a unit test if you follow the usual extension approach to registering your services. Arrange the list of types that should be registered, call your reg extensions, and validate the contents. The only thing I don't think you can do is confirm they're registered with the correct lifetime.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddFunctionsServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services
        .AddTransient<Foo>()
        .AddTransient<Bar>()
        .AddTransient<Baz>();
}

[Fact]
public void RegisteredServices()
{
    var types = new List<Type>{ typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar), typeof(Baz) };
    var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddFunctionsServices()
        .AddSomeOtherServices()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    foreach(var t in types)
        Assert.NotNull(provider.GetService<t>());
}
```

If registration happens in a separate library used by different apps (I actually do this myself with a library that supports Functions, web apps, and command-line utilities), you can easily set up different tests for the list of services required by each library consumer.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I figured. Trouble with this is that it still requires me to "know" all the places that the service with the updated dependency is. Say I have a service called IService1 and I have just added a new dependency in the constructor of that services implementation for IService2 I have to manually find that it's used in functions 1,3,5 and update their dependencies. I was hoping someone might know a way to test that the tree for each service hadn't changed to a state where something was now missing.

Comment: I went through the same process myself with DI and Functions. The thing is, _registering_ a service is quick and cheap. Services don't get created until they're requested, so carefully pruning the list for each Functions app ends up being wasted premature optimization. I had two distinct Functions use-cases, so I ended up with `AddFunctionsServices`, `AddFunctionsParserServices`, `AddAspNetCoreServices`, and `AddMaintenanceServices` (for command line utils) extensions for the whole system.

Comment: So essentially I should just register them all using the same methods I do in my web app and the overhead is so minimal I'm just being picky? :)

Comment: Sure, if you use them all. As you can see, I still differentiate, but not on an individual function basis. I should note that each of those "top level" extensions each call different additional service registration extensions, and in a couple of cases there is even a third layer in the mix -- I definitely know the pain of multiple dependency combinations and I'm going to implement this unit test approach myself...